# C#/.NET Lexer Generators

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, generator, lexical-analysis

I'm looking for a decent lexical scanner generator for C#/.NET -- something that supports Unicode character categories, and generates somewhat readable & efficient code.  Anyone know of one?

---

EDIT: I ***need*** support for **Unicode categories**, not just Unicode characters.  There are currently 1421 characters in just the `Lu` (Letter, Uppercase) category alone, and I need to match many different categories very specifically, and would rather not hand-write the character sets necessary for it.

Also, actual code is a ***must*** -- this rules out things that generate a binary file that is then used with a driver (i.e. GOLD)

---

EDIT: ANTLR does not support Unicode categories yet.  There is an [open issue](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/define+unicode+aliases+for+character+categories) for it, though, so it might fit my needs someday.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GPLEX seems to support your requirements.

Comment: How the hell did I never know about GPPG?

Comment: I have been using it for years now  :)  GPLEX only recently (last year).

Answer (score 1):

The two solutions that come to mind are [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) and [Gold](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/).  ANTLR has a GUI based grammar designer, and an excellent sample project in C# [can be found here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sota_expression_evaluator.aspx).

Comment: Gold doesn't generate /code/ for the lexer -- it builds a special binary file that a driver then reads at runtime.  As for Antlr, I can't find anything that even implies that it supports Unicode /classes/ (it seems to allow specified unicode characters, but not entire classes)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @David Robbins, ANTLR is probably your best bet. However, the generated ANTLR code does need a seperate runtime library in order to use the generated code because there are some string parsing and other library commonalities that the generated code relies on. ANTLR generates a lexer AND a parser.

On a side note: 
ANTLR is great...I wrote a 400+ line grammar to generate over 10k or C# code to efficiently parse a language. This included built in error checking for every possible thing that could go wrong in the parsing of the language. Try to do that by hand, and you'll never keep up with the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this

http://www.seclab.tuwien.ac.at/projects/cuplex/lex.htm

It says that it's configurable enough to support unicode ;-).

Herber